# PHP variable in function is getting reset

Tags: php

I have a function in PHP and it is taking an array of strings and adding how many { characters are in each line, then subtracting how many } characters are in each line. However, my $braceCount parameter is reset when it goes into the next if statement. Any thoughts?

```
function BraceHandler($txt, $strtLine){
$linecount = count($txt);
$braceCount = 0;
$arrayBrace = null;
for ($x = $strtLine; $x <= $linecount; $x++) {
    $arrayBrace = null;
    $arrayBrace = explode("{", $txt[$x]);
    if (count($arrayBrace) > 1){
        $braceCount = $braceCount + (count($arrayBrace) - 1);
        ConsoleLog("Brace count is currently " . $braceCount);
        //This would say that $braceCount = 1
    }
    $arrayBrace = null;
    $arrayBrace = explode("}", $txt[$x]);
    if (count($arrayBrace) > 1){
        ConsoleLog("Brace count is currently " . $braceCount);
        // I havent subtracted anything here so this should say $braceCount = 1
        // But it says 0
    }
}
```

}

The $txt is an array with.

```
Data1
Data1
Data1
{
    Data1=1
    Data1=1
    Data1=1
    Data1=1
    Data1=1
    Data1=1
}
Data1
DAta2
```

And $strtLine can be 0.

Comment: [Doesn't appear to happen.](https://3v4l.org/vNPce) Had to change `$x <= $linecount` to `$x < $linecount`, but other than that, that's your exact function.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. Can you show us what the input you're testing with looks like? On a side note, it would be simpler if you used `foreach` instead of `for`.

Comment: can you share sample data of `$txt`, `$strtLine`

Comment: Edited the post with $txt and $strtLine

Comment: Your array structure is unclear. Does each line represent an element of the array?

Comment: Your problem is on the for loop line. It should be $x < $linecount. And not <=.